# delegate and protocol not working correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I am trying to pass data back from one TabBarViewController to my MasterViewController however when tyring to pass data back to the MasterViewController the method from my protocol/Delegate never gets accessed.

This is what I have done -
I have a TabBarViewcontroller and a MasterViewController, the TabBarController is added to the MasterViewController as a subview... what I am trying to do is then load another subview onto the MasterViewController which I plan to do when a tabbarbutton is selected in the tabBarViewController i call my protocol/delegate method. for this I am using the following code. (I hope this makes sense so far)

TabBarViewController.h

```
@class MasterViewController;

@protocol LoadActionView <NSObject>
@required
- (void) loadViewsAction;
@end

@interface TabBarViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate> {


    __weak id <LoadActionView> delegate;

//..
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) id delegate;

//..
```

TabBarViewController.m

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    switch (item.tag) {
        case 0:
        {
             NSLog(@"item 1 selected");
            [[self delegate] loadViewsAction]; //the thread defiantly makes it here as I have debugged to this point
        }
//..
```

then, 
MasterViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "TabBarViewController.h"

    @interface MasterViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, LoadActionView> {


TabBarViewController *tbVC;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) TabBarViewController *tbVC;
    //..
```

MasterViewController.m

```
#import "TabBarViewController.h"

@synthesize tbVC;
    //..

- (void) viewDidLoad {
//..

tbVC = [[TabBarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabBarViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIView *tbView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 367.0, 320.0, 49.0)];
    [tbView addSubview:tbVC.view];
    [otherNav.view addSubview:tbView];


}

    - (void) loadViewsAction
    {
        NSLog(@"HITME!"); //threads not making it here.
    }
```

the only thing different form what I normally do here is the fact that this TabBarViewController is being added as a subview.. so I am woundering if thats screwing things up.. but if so I have no idea how to fix...

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you assign loadActionView.delegate = self; in MasterViewController?

Comment: oh, no I havent.. however just tried to do that inside the viewDidLoad method of MasterViewController and its giving me this error **Use of undeclared identifier 'loadActionView'**

Comment: @xingzhi.sg not sure if your saw my last msg but trying ti implement the code you said dose not seem to work.

Comment: @xingzhi.sg is assuming that your `TabBarController` instance is named `loadActionView` in `MasterViewController`. You need to replace that with the name you used in your code. Please update your question to include the code where you initialize an instance of `TabBarController`.

Comment: @DavidAlber yup, I have added the lines of code where I have called TabBarControllerView

Comment: The thing is loadActionView is the name of the @protocol in my tabbarviewcontroller. so I thought he was referring to that @protocol?

Comment: Try tbVC.delegate = self;  just as the other two commentors have asked.

Comment: yep.. thats it.. I had just tried it.. dang.. I got confused because @xingzhi.sg had used my protocol name so I thought i had to do that.. gah! well now I know will never make that mistake again!

Comment: My apology. Yes I intended to say your viewController instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug the problem by adding:

```
NSAssert (nil != [self delegate]);
```

just before the call to `loadViewsAction`.  That assert will fail because you have not assigned the TabBarController's delegate.  After creating the TabVarController, perform:

```
tbVS.delegate = self;
```

You'll then have a delegate to use for loadViewsAction.